# Python Lists how to merge two or more comprehensions?

Tags: python, list

```
FirstList = [10, 20, 23, 11, 17]
SecondList = [13, 43, 24, 36, 12]

thirdlist = [num for num in FirstList if num%2==1]
thirdlist.extend([num for num in SecondList if num%2==0])
print(thirdlist)
```

So my question is how can i erase `thirdlist.extend()` and compile in one line? My approach was

```
thirdlist=[num for num in FirstList if num%2==1 , num1 for num1 in Second ...]
```

Desired output for above example:

```
[23, 11, 17, 24, 36, 12]'
```

Comment: in this case '[23, 11, 17, 24, 36, 12]'

Comment: `[a for a in FirstList if a%2==1] + [a for a in SecondList if a%2==0]`

Comment: You *could* use `[*(genexpr), *(genexpr)]` but your going to end up wanting to put it on multiple lines anyway. There's nothing wrong with your approach

Comment: i was thinking about genexpr too but i wanted to know if there is a way to sum them in one line

Comment: I just gave you one way. Concatenating the results of the list comprehension is another way as mentioned above

Comment: It might be too obvious, but lists can be added to each other. So rewriting the `thirdlist.exend([<list comprehension>])` with `thirdlist + [<list comprehension>]` is doable. Doing this for the first list comprehension as well, would result in a single line like `result = [<first list comprehension>] + [<second list comprehension>]`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it using `+` both of the `list comprehension` in one line,

```
FirstList = [10, 20, 23, 11, 17]
SecondList = [13, 43, 24, 36, 12]
thirdlist = [num for num in FirstList if num%2==1] + [num for num in SecondList if num%2==0]
print(thirdlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain` instead of `+`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain([num for num in FirstList if num%2==1], [num for num in SecondList if num%2==0]))
[23, 11, 17, 24, 36, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is, in some sense, a syntactic wrapper around a generator expression. In this case, I would explicitly use generator expressions, and chain them together with `itertools.chain`. This approach has the advantage of creating *one* list object, not two temporary objects that are used to create the third, final object.

```
from itertools import chain


FirstList = [10, 20, 23, 11, 17]
SecondList = [13, 43, 24, 36, 12]

thirdList = list(chain((num for num in FirstList if num % 2 == 1),
                       (num for num in SecondList if num % 2 == 0)))
print(thirdlist)
```

You might also want to use `filter` instead of a generator expression for readability.

```
thirdList = list(chain(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 1, FirstList),
                       filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, SecondList))
```

or

```
def even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

def odd(x):
    return x % 2 == 1

thirdList = list(chain(filter(even, FirstList), filter(odd, SecondList)))
```